# How to use Model function in controller?

Tags: yii

**model**:

```
public function week($gid)
{

    $sensor = Yii::app()->zdb->createCommand("select nid ,sdata,stype,timestamp from tbl_sensor where timestamp >= date('now','-30 days') antimestamp<date('now');")->queryAll();
    return $sensor;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model Should be:

```
public function week()
{

$sensor = Yii::app()->zdb->createCommand("select nid ,sdata,stype,timestamp from tbl_sensor where timestamp >= date('now','-30 days') antimestamp<date('now');")->queryAll();
return $sensor;

}
```

And Your Controller Should Be:

```
public function actionReport() { 
    $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId()); 
    $gwinfo =Sensor::model()->find('(gid)=?', array($user->gid)); 
    $model='';
    if(isset($_POST['week'])) { 
         $model= Sensor::model()->week(); 
    } 
    //$this->render('Reportht', array('gw'=>$gwinfo, 'user'=>$user)); 

    $this->redirect('index.php?r=site/report', array('gw'=>$gwinfo, 'user'=>$user,'model'=>$model)); 
}
```

**NOTE:** I have passed `model` object to your view now you can use that object when needed

Comment: hi mycontroller is  public function actionReport()
        { 
          $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId());
               $gwinfo =Sensor::model()->find('(gid)=?', array($user->gid));
                
                if(isset($_POST['week'])) {
                        $model= Sensor::model()->week($gid);
          } 
                //$this->render('Reportht', array('gw'=>$gwinfo, 'user'=>$user));
                 $this->redirect('index.php?r=site/reports', array('gw'=>$gwinfo, 'user'=>$user));    
       }

Comment: i got error about undefined Undefined variable: gid   so plz let me know ho to do?

Comment: Do you have a column in the user table or variable name in User model as `gid` ?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['week'])) {
    $model= Sensor::model()->week($gid);
}`

Here you are using `$gid` local variable but it not defined within your `actionReport()`

Comment: I can have a guess that the line `$model= Sensor::model()->week($gid);` should be `$model= Sensor::model()->week($user->gid);` according to your code.

Comment: ok now i got following error 
Error 404
The system is unable to find the requested action "index.php".

Comment: plz help me out , thinkDiffrent

Comment: ok change the last line to `$this->redirect('index.php?r=site/report', array('gw'=>$gwinfo, 'user'=>$user)); `

Comment: Check the updated answer, I have just changed the redirect statement

Comment: Again it showing the same thing ,my view is <?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle='Wisys ' . Yii::app()->user->appName() . ' Report';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
 'Sensors',
);

echo CHtml::beginForm(array('Sensor/report'), 'post');
echo CHtml::submitButton('One Week', array('name'=>"week", 'style'=>"float: left"));
echo CHtml::endForm();
?>

Comment: Ok I think you don't need the $gid both in model and in your controller. I am updating the answer again !!!

Comment: array('label'=>'Reports', 'url'=>array('/site/reports') this is my main.php in view/layout

Comment: Do you have a `public function actionReports()` in your controller? If No then your urls are wrong use it as `array('site/report')` as from your controller you showed me just `public function actionReport()`

Comment: in my sitecontroller i have   public function actionReports()
 {
  $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId());
  if ($user === NULL) {
   throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page is no longr valid. Please login again.');
   return;
  }

  $gwinfo = Gateway::model()->find('(gid)=?', array($user->gid));
  if ($gwinfo === null) {
   throw new CHttpException(404,'There is no activated gateway yet.');
   return;
  }

  $this->render('Reportht', array('gw'=>$gwinfo, 'user'=>$user));
 }

Comment: when i use array('site/report') i got  the same result

Comment: You are not asking the right question then. Ok one last try what is in your view `Reportht` ?

Comment: it is same page as report

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for "How to create a method in Model and how to use in Controller"

Try like this

1. create a method in Model called "MyModel"

   ```
   function foo($param)
   {            
       $model = ModelName::model()->findAll("property=$param");
       return $model;
   }
   ```
2. Using it in my Controller

   ```
   function actionBar()
   {
       $result=MyModel::model()->foo($param);
       //print_r($result);
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I hope to God you are not overwriting the existing model to create your own query. If so, it is not best to do that in your model. You should read more about PDO because using that query will be more vulnerable to SQL injections. You should put your query in your controller by using CActiveRecord. You can read this [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) as it is very intuitive and very easy to learn. You should not modify your Model unless needed.

If by any chance you are using a custom query for querying your database. You can use CDbCriteria to generate a custom query.

Comment: I don't see any sql injection vulnerability in this query `"select nid ,sdata,stype,timestamp from tbl_sensor where timestamp >= date('now','-30 days') and timestamp < date('now');"`. ActiveRecords are best if you have a resonable size tables, If not then using ActiveRecords in Yii is not a good idea (Performace issue)